# Ajax can't load the data

Tags: php, ajax

Actually I am trying to get the data without refreshing the page. The below are the coding which I done for this.

Here file name config php used to connect with database

index php file code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax Demo</title>
</head> 
<body>
Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="name" id="name-submit" value="Get Data"/>
<div id="name-data"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/getdata.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for getdata js file

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function(){
    var name = $ ('input#name').val();
    if($.trim(name) != ''){
        $.post('name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
            $('div#name-data').text(data);*/
        });
    }
});
```

and at last the name php file code is below

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * 
FROM `temp` 
WHERE `name`.`name`='". mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) ."'");

$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);

echo ($num !== 0) ? mysqli_result($query, 0, 'lastname') : 'Name Not Forund' ;
}
?></code>
```

Comment: You have `*/`, but no matching `/*` in the JS.

Comment: Also `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires DB connection.

Comment: I know it require the DB connection and that is why I write "require "../config.php" this is a database connection file

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php it will explain my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any input with the id="name"! `var name = $ ('input#name').val();` you can fix this using the this code : `var name = $ ('input[name="name"]').val();`

Comment: Replace it but still when I enter the value I get nothing in response

Comment: You also forgot to remove the closing of a comment in this line : `$('div#name-data').text(data);*/`

Comment: try to log the value of the recovered input value, `console.log(name)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="name"/>
```

should be

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
```

according to your code

Answer (score 0):

Add **ID** attribute to the below input element to get the value.

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
```

Then put below code to get the value of above input.

```
var name = $('#name').val();
```

Also check data at client side by below to check ajax response.

```
console.log(data);
```

**General Note :** I can't see any database connection so please check this too at your end.

Comment: Tip: OP is using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` incorrectly. Most likely reason why OP isn't successful with any of the answers given.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
var name = $ ('input#name').val();
```

to

```
var name = $ ('input#name-submit').val();
```

Comment: ,he wants text-box value not button value.You have specified button id to get value instead of text-box id.